# CodeIgniter query result is returning array as $user['0']->name. How can i get it as $user->name?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Model function

```
public function getUserByID($id) 
    {
        $q = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id), 1);
        $user= $q->result();
        if($user) {
        return $user;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
    }
```

Controller code

```
$data['user'] = $this->users_model->getUserByID($id);
```

View file code

```
<pre><?php print_r($user); ?></pre>

Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Saleem
            [city] => Kuala Lumput
            [state] => WP
            [postal_code] => 58100
            [country] => Malaysia
            [phone] => 0123456789

        )
)
```

How can i get the result as below.

```
Array
(
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Saleem
            [city] => Kuala Lumput
            [state] => WP
            [postal_code] => 58100
            [country] => Malaysia
            [phone] => 0123456789
)
```

as now I need to use it as $user['0']->name; I want to use it as $user->name; Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way of doing this in CI would be using the `$result->row()` method:

```
public function getUserByID($id) 
{ 
  $q = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id), 1); 
  if( $q->num_rows() > 0 )
  {
    return $q->row();
  }

  return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

let the function `getUserByID` return the first user

it should solve the problem

```
    public function getUserByID($id) 
    {
        $q = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id), 1);
        $user= $q->result();
        if(count($user) == 1) {
        return $user[0];
        } else {
        return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, It worked. I am wounder is CI multidimensional array. Is there any other way to avoid ['0']. I am beginner and learning CI.

Comment: @Saleem Yes,there is a way...check my answer

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
$data['user'][0] = $this->users_model->getUserByID($id);
```

You can directly get from the controller itself

or from model you can go through like

```
public function getUserByID($id) 
{
    $q = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id), 1);
    $user= $q->result();
    if(count($user) == 1) {
    return $user[0];
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Controller**:

```
$data['user'] = $this->users_model->getUserByID($id);
foreach($data['user'] as $user)
{
$result = $user;
}
print_r($result);
```

will give you

```
Array
(
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Saleem
        [city] => Kuala Lumput
        [state] => WP
        [postal_code] => 58100
        [country] => Malaysia
        [phone] => 0123456789
 )
```

**EDIT:**

Or you can do this at model

```
public function getUserByID($id) 
{
    $q = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id), 1);
    $user= $q->result();
    if(count($user) > 0) 
    {
      foreach($user as $out)
      {
       $blah = $out;
      }
    return $blah;
    } 
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Saleem Check this and report the output..You can get this without using `[0]`

Comment: It worked thank you again. I want to ask you one more thing.. How can i set value <?php echo form_input($company, $user->name, 'class="text"');?> is not working

Comment: @Saleem What is `$comapny` inside form_input? That should be the input name...not a variable

Comment: Sorry I copied wrong line, i have solve it as this <?php $name = array(
              'name'        => 'name',
              'id'          => 'name',
              'value'       => $user->name,
              'class'       => 'text',
            ); ?> and used <?php echo form_input($name);?> to display input :)

Answer (score 0):

Modify your model function and make it like this

```
public function getUserByID($id) 
{
    $q = $this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $id), 1);
    $user= $q->result_array();
    if($user) {
    return $user;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```